# Referencing higherframe data from a lower timefram

Tags: pine-script

I'm trying to reference 15m data on a 1m chart. But it seems that the new data on the 1m chart isn't showing the new data until 1 minute later. For example, when it turns 1:00, we get a new 15m bar and a new 1m bar, I would expect the new data to be accessible on the 1m chart, but the new data isn't updated until 1:01.

```
//@version=5
strategy("HTF Data", overlay=true)

HTF    = "15"
HTFClose  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF, close[1])
HTFClose2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF, close[2])
HTFEMA1 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF, ta.ema(close[1], 8))
HTFEMA2 = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF, ta.ema(close[2], 8))

var testTable = table.new(position = position.top_right, columns = 1, rows = 4, bgcolor = color.yellow, border_width = 1)
if barstate.islast
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 0, text = "HTFClose: " + str.tostring(HTFClose))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 1, text = "HTFClose2: " + str.tostring(HTFClose2), bgcolor=color.white)
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 2, text = "HTFEMA1: " + str.tostring(HTFEMA1))
    table.cell(table_id = testTable, column = 0, row = 3, text = "HTFEMA2: " + str.tostring(HTFEMA2), bgcolor=color.white)
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on`.

Please read [this](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v4/essential/Context_switching_the_security_function.html#understanding-lookahead) for more information.

```
//@version=5
strategy("HTF Data", overlay=true)

HTF    = "15"
HTFClose  = request.security(syminfo.tickerid, HTF, close, lookahead=barmerge.lookahead_on)
plot(HTFClose)
```

[image]